# seabornのsizeを変更したい

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv('csv/gaku-mg1712_02_21ver3.csv', encoding='shift_jis',
    parse_dates={'date':['名目時系列']}, index_col='date')
#gdpDate = df['1994-03-01':'1994-12-01',df['国内総生産']]
#df['国内総生産']
#五年ごとの平均と分散によるヒストグラムの作成を行う？？

searchData1 = df.iloc[np.where(('1994-03-01'<= df.index) & (df.index <= '1999-12-01'))]
searchData2 = df.iloc[np.where(('2000-03-01'<= df.index) & (df.index <= '2004-12-01'))]
searchData3 = df.iloc[np.where(('2005-03-01'<= df.index) & (df.index <= '2009-12-01'))]
searchData4 = df.iloc[np.where(('2010-03-01'<= df.index) & (df.index <= '2015-12-01'))]
sns.set()
sns.set_context("notebook")
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
sns.distplot(searchData1['国内総生産'],
             hist=False,
             kde_kws={"color": "k", "lw": 3, "label": "gdp_1995-2000"}, # 凡例の色、線の太さ、名前を記述
             axlabel='gdp'
             )
sns.distplot(searchData2['国内総生産'],
             hist=False,
             kde_kws={"color": "b", "lw": 3, "label": "gdp_2000-2005"}, # 凡例の色、線の太さ、名前を記述
             axlabel='gdp'
            )
sns.distplot(searchData3['国内総生産'],
             hist=False,
             kde_kws={"color": "r", "lw": 3, "label": "gdp_2005-2010"}, # 凡例の色、線の太さ、名前を記述
             axlabel='gdp')
sns.distplot(searchData4['国内総生産'],
             hist=False,
             kde_kws={"color": "y", "lw": 3, "label": "gdp_2010-2015"}, # 凡例の色、線の太さ、名前を記述
             axlabel='gdp')
```

曲線がはみ出てしまいます。どうしたら改善できますか？
[image: 図1.gdpのグラフ]

Answer (score 1):

ylimで調整できませんでしたか？

```
plt.ylim([0.0, 0.0002])
```

Comment: そのまま記述するとできました。